# MS Access rounding SQL decimal places

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, rounding

I currently run a process of using MS Access 2010 to import an Excel file into a SQL table. There are fields within this data that numeric fields calculated to 4 decimal places.

Access imports this to a field within the SQL table which is set up as [decimal](19, 4), where is displays fine.  However, when I try to use Access to work with the data in this linked table, it converts it to 2 decimal places.

Access identifies this field as currency and assigns the decimal places to auto.

Is there any way I can use Access to query this data but to show 4 decimal places?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Using MS Access - Open the table in Design View. Click on the Currency field. Now you can see the Field Properties, where is the Decimal Places. Select the number of digits, 4 in your case, and save the table. I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this and it adds an extra two zeros on to the end of the value. For example the value within the linked SQL table is 1305.3360 and this shows as 1305.3400.

Comment: Reimport the data in the adapted table.

Comment: This still shows the rounded amount - even after I truncate and reimport.

Comment: Another way is to do Data Type - Currency. Format : €#,####0.0000;-€#,####0.0000 Decimal Places - 4. And as Thomas G said - re-import the data. Try as well to modify one record and save it to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your help Gabriel and Thomas G.  I have tried that and it doesn't seem to work. What is slightly more annoying is that it is in the SQL table as 4 decimal places and rounded within Access!

Comment: When you run reports (queries) in Access, in the Report Designer View you have to right click the Currency field and and select Property. Property Sheet will be displayed on the right side of the screen. Now you can modify the decimal places here too, to render appropriately.

Comment: Thanks - this didn't seem to work either, just added 00 to the rounded number.  I will have to have another look at the way that I process the data.